# Labeling % of total on stacked bar chart in Tableau

Tags: excel, bar-chart, label, tableau-api, stacked

I am trying to create a stacked bar chart with dollars on the vertical axis, date on the horizontal, and three separate qualitative measures (dollar value is divided between all three of the measures). I'm looking for a way to label each section of the bar with the percent of the total (labels fall inside each section of the bar).

The data that I have is the date, category, Total $'s, category 1 $'s, category 2 $'s, category 3 $'s.

Up to this point, I have taken the date pill and dropped it in column, taken measure values and dropped it in rows, taken measure name and dropped it in color in the marks box. I'm left with a stacked bar to my liking. So I am pretty much looking for a way to label each portion of each bar with  say the sum of cat. 1 divided by the sum of the total bar.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple. Drag Total $ again to the rows, then right-click, quick table calculation, percent of total. Then right click again, Compute using, Cell.

This will give you the percentages. Now just drag this created field to Label